# Can I make the same laravel web app online and local too?

Tags: database, laravel, web, database-design, web-applications

I am trying to design a web app that should function both locally and online, so if the internet is down people on the local network can still use it to display and update data. Then when the internet is back users can access it online once again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have more than one approaches. I could only speak of those I know.

1. You develop on your company/house server, and make your local network/server available on the Internet. When the internet is down, users on local network can still access it. There are some resources explaining how to do that online, e.g: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/accessible-local-web-server/
2. Use a Javascript frontend (AngularJS, ReactJS, etc.) and make use of `LocalStorage` to save everything people do when offline. These people make good use of it: https://en.todoist.com/. You can create an account, sign in and then go offline. You will still be able to use it offline and it will sync when your connection comes back.

Those are the 2 I am aware of. Now it's entirely up to you to research their advantages and drawbacks and make your own decision.